# re-Naming variables by properties (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

In a JavaScript code, I am trying to re-name an object by its stored data. I tried using pathTo as suggested by this site (http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000381.html), but my console returns "ReferenceError: 'pathTo' is undefined".  My code looks something like this:

```
// This code defines the Object constructor Card, used to make the card objects
var Card = function() {
    this.face = theFace(this);
    this.suit = theSuit(this);
    this.value = theValue(this);
};

// This code creates the Deck to be used.
var deck = [];
for ( i=0 ; i<52 ; i++ ) {
    deck.push( i );
};
for ( i=51 ; i>0 ; i-- ) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
    var temp = deck[random];
    deck[random] = deck[i];
    deck[i] = temp;
};
// 0-12 is Spades.
// 13-25 is Hearts.
// 26-38 is Clubs.
// 39-51 is Diamonds.

// Now we create the hand of the player and dealer
var player = [];
var dealer = [];

// Now to deal a card to player
player.push(deck.pop());
dealer.push(deck.pop());

// and another
player.push(deck.pop());
dealer.push(deck.pop());

// function theFace gives the face of a card
function theFace( card ) {
    var faces = ["King","Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Queen","Jack"];
    return(faces[card%13]);
};

// function theValue uses 'switch' to determine points from a card
function theValue(card) {
    var value = card % 13;
    switch( value ) {

        case(0):
        case(11):
        case(12):
            value = 10;
            break;

        case(1):
            value = 11;
            break;

        default:
            value = value;
            break;

    };
    return value;
};

// function theSuit returns the suit of a card
function theSuit(card) {
    var suit;
    if(card>38) {
        suit = "Diamonds";
    }else if(card>25) {
        suit = "Clubs";
    }else if(card>12) {
        suit = "Hearts";
    }else {
        suit = "Spades";
    };
    return suit;
};

// function toObject the first (numbered) card of of a hand 
// and turns it into an Object with the desired properties
function toObject( hand ) {
    var card = hand.shift();
    if (typeof(card) !== "number") {
        hand.unshift(card);
    } else {
        var card = new Card ();
        card = pathTo[card.suit + card.face];
    };
    return hand;
};

console.log(player);
toObject(player);
toObject(player);
console.log(player);
```

I am trying to rename the card I am turning from a typeof==="number" to typeof==="object" so that when I run the code multiple times (hence the function) I do not have duplicate names of the objects in the array of hands.

Here are some examples of what my console is printing:

```
[ 19, 46 ]
ReferenceError: 'pathTo' is undefined
```

and

```
[ 31, 18 ]
ReferenceError: 'pathTo' is undefined
```

There MUST be a way to do this, I just cannot find how.

In function toObject I am trying to take the first number(card) in the hand array and turn it into an object describing its qualifiers as a card of the standard 52 card deck.  EDIT: I just realized I'm not even pushing it back.  I am going to try something to see if it will work.

EDITEDITEDIT_SOLVED:
I have done it!  It turns out that I don't need to change the name, the code will keep it separate for me somehow. All I needed to do so that it runs correctly is this:

Replace

```
var Card = function() { 
    this.face = theFace(this); 
    this.suit = theSuit(this); 
    this.value = theValue(this); 
};
```

with

```
var Card = function(card) {
    this.face = theFace(card);
    this.suit = theSuit(card);
    this.value = theValue(card);
};
```

and

```
function toObject( hand ) {   
    var card = hand.shift();   
    if (typeof(card) !== "number") {   
        hand.unshift(card);   
    } else {   
        var card = new Card ();   
        card = pathTo[card.suit + card.face];   
    };   
    return hand;   
};
```

with

```
function toObject( hand ) {
    var card = hand.shift();
    if (typeof(card) !== "number") {
        hand.unshift(card);
    } else {
        var card = new Card (card);
        hand.push(card);
    };
    return hand;
};
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you explain in plain English what you're trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: sorry, I thought I did.  What I am doing is taking a #r standing for a card in a deck of 52 cards (0-51) and turning it, while in the hand array, to an object describing its properties.  However, I need to generate a name for the card, and that is where `pathTo` is creating a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: My main problem is trying to change the name of card so I don't end up with multiple card objects in my array.

Comment: pathTo isn't a javascript function. In the link you provided, pathTo appears to be a previously defined object that the author doesn't show the code for. Basically what the author is doing is showing an alternative to the dot notation for getting at properties of an object - the array notation. If you define an object `var card = new Card();`, then you could add a dynamic property called `card['card' + (card.suit + card.face)]` and assign a value to it. You can't do that with dot notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mattbornski points out, there is no `pathTo` object in JavaScript and, as far as I know, it's not supported by any browser anywhere. That article seems to have omitted this part of their code.

Based on how you're trying to use it, though, you'll want to make a few changes to your code:

Create a `pathTo` object like this:

```
pathTo = {};
```

or

```
pathTo = new Object();
```

Then, give each new `Card` object a suit and face before you try to add it to `pathTo` (or before you try to use it to look up a card). For example, you could write:

```
myCard = new Card(23);
```

or

```
myCard = new Card('spade','2');
```

Finally, when your card has both a face and a suit, add it to the `pathTo` object like this:

```
pathTo[this.suit + this.face] = this; // use this inside the Card constructor
```

or

```
pathTo[myCard.suit + myCard.face] = myCard; // use this with an instance of a Card object
```

Then you can look up the cards with:

```
pathTo['spade2']
```

Answer (score 0):

The website you are reading from is documenting array syntax.  It is not documenting a function called pathTo - there is no such built in function, so referring to it will cause a ReferenceError.

Perhaps you should define an object and refer to that instead.